# printing a vector of string in static text box with new lines

Tags: matlab

I have a bunch of classes that I am iterating through and collecting which classes the student is failing in.  If the student fails , I collect the name of the class in a vector called retake.

```
retake =[Math History Science]
```

I have line breaks so when the classes print in the command window it shows as:

retake=

Math

History

Science.

However,  I am trying display retake in a static text box in Gui Guide so it looks like the above.  Instead, the static text box is showing as:

MathHistoryScience

```
 set(handles.text13,'String', retake)  % this is what I tried
```

can you please show me so it prints:

Math

History

Science

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you need to add carriage returns.

Assuming you have a *cell array* with strings (rather than concatenated strings using `[]`, which will give you a single long line), you can do it as follows:

```
retake = {'Math', 'History', 'Science'};

rString = '';
for ii = 1:numel(retake)-1
  rString = [rString sprintf('%s\n', retake{ii}];
end
rString = [rString retake{end}];
```

Notice the use of `''` to denote strings, `{}` to denote a *cell array*, `'\n'` as the end-of-line character, and `[a b]` to do simple string concatenation.